# What is the privatekey to be used to sign web3.js transactions?

Tags: web3js, wallets, private-key

I created an account on metamask, and downloaded the json of my wallet.

It's on rinkeby.

The structure of the json is

```
{
    "version":3,"
    id":"...",
    "address":"....",
    "crypto":
        {
            "ciphertext":"....",
            "cipherparams":{ "iv":"..." },
            "cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
            "kdf":"scrypt",
            "kdfparams":
                {
                    "dklen":...,
                    "salt":"...",
                    "n":...,
                    "r":...,
                    "p":...
                },
            "mac":"..."
        }
}
```

My question is related to web3.js, where signing transaction requires a private key.

What is this private key? Is part of the json above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also obtain it programmatically:

```
const keythereum = require("keythereum");
console.log(keythereum.recover(yourPassword, yourJsonObject).toString("hex"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.

On metamask, I can export private key of selected account

[image]

Click on the threedots

[image]

Click on Account details

[image]

Click on export private key.

It now ask you a password: it's the *Metamask* password. It's specific to metamask.

Then it will show you the private key.

Keep it absolutely private, do not share, do not save on cloud!